# Spring Boot: ValidationMessages found but ContributorValidationMessages not found?

Tags: json, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, bean-validation

I am building web APIs with Spring Boot. One of the end point takes post request with JSON. I want to set up Validation Messages on some of the fields. So I added a `ValidationMessages.properties` under /src/main/resources along with `application.properties`. The following lines were added to that file:

```
doorid.notnull=Door ID is required
doorid.notblank=Door ID is empty
```

In my entity class for the JSON, I have the field "doorId" annotated like this:

```
    @NotNull(message = "{doorid.notnull}")
    @NotBlank (message = "{doorid.notblank}")
    private String doorId;
```

When I tested the API with doorId as empty string though, it just returned code 406 without any messages. In the server log, it says:

```
ValidationMessages found.
ContributorValidationMessages not found.
```

What exactly is `ContributorValidationMessages`? Why do I need that in addition to `ValidationMessages`?

**EDIT**:

After adding a `ContributorValidationMessages.properties` in the same path with the same lines as `ValidationMessages.properties`, it seems to find everything.

```
ValidationMessages found.
ContributorValidationMessages found.
org.hibernate.validator.ValidationMessages found.
```

However, when I tried the same request with empty `doorId`, it only returns 406. The validation message is not shown anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`ContributorValidationMessages` is a property file to place default messages for custom constraints.

According to related [blog post](http://in.relation.to/2017/03/02/adding-custom-constraint-definitions-via-the-java-service-loader/):

> The bundle ContributorValidationMessages is queried by Hibernate
>   Validator if the standard ValidationMessages bundle doesn’t contain a
>   given message key, allowing library authors to provide default
>   messages for their constraints as part of their JAR.

And according to related [document](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=6.0#_constraint_definitions_via_code_serviceloader_code):

> This mechanism is also helpful when creating large multi-module
>   applications: Instead of putting all the constraint messages into one
>   single bundle, you can have one resource bundle per module containing
>   only those messages of that module.

Comment: so instead of using ValidationMessages.properties, I should use ContributorValidationmessages.properties instead with the same content?

Comment: If it's needed to place default messages for custom constraints in your situation, for example for a multi-module application as mentioned above, yes you should use `ContributorValidationMessages`.

Comment: What exactly is a multi-module application. I only have one pom

Comment: You can read [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/) to be informed. Happy coding!

Comment: Apparently my application is not a multi-module application. From your first quotation, it sounds like `ContributorValidationMessages` is just a supplementary file. If the message key is not found in `ValidationMessages`, it will look there. However, the message was found in `ValidationMessages`, why does it still look for `ContributorValidationMessages`?